# When does drawing additional samples not cause much benefit in estimating the population probability distribution?

Tags: probability, inference, sequential-analysis

Suppose I have a random variable X that either evaluates to A, B, or C when I realize it (each with its own fixed probability). Now let's say I have drawn 100 samples and the frequency distribution is something like

```
A  30    
B  55   
C  15
```

dividing by n=100 gives me the probability estimates.

However, when do I have a 95% chance of being $\delta$ close to the true population probabilities?

EDIT: I'm not precise enough with that question. Does $\delta$ refer to the best deviation, the worst deviation or the average deviation? If some of them are tricky please just assume the simple interpretation. I just need a rule of thumb.

Comment: can I suggest you make your second question into a separate question?

Comment: Yes, it seems to require vastly different techniques. I will separate it.

Comment: Why does this question have a `sequential-analysis` tag? It is a possible take on the question, but I'm curious whether that's actually what you're after or not.

Comment: To clarify - aside from whuber's comment and your inclusion of the tag, it doesn't look to me like you're asking about that kind of approach, which is why I wondered.

Comment: whuber included the tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a sampling size determination problem, check wikipedia on that.  In your case, you are estimating a multinomial distribution, for which you might want to check out this old [article from JSTOR](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2684318?uid=3739864&uid=2&uid=4&uid=3739256&sid=21103853183113), or maybe this [more recent freely available one](http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~cgga/jfs2009mavridis.pdf).

Comment: Framing this as a sample size determination is helpful but I wonder whether an approach based on sequential sampling theory might be even more fruitful.